# Change colors and pattern fill on stacked grouped barplot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I also like to be able to change the colors and patterns of the stacked bars on a grouped stacked barplot using ggplot.

I would usually use `scale_fill_manual` and `geom_col_pattern` but those will not work as they turn my plot back into one group.

Is there a way around this issue?

[image]

```
set.seed(687532)                     # Create example data frame
data <- data.frame(facet = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 6),
                   group = c("x", "y"),
                   stack = letters[1:3],
                   value = round(abs(rnorm(30)), 2))

ggplot(data,                         # Draw barplot with grouping & stacking
       aes(x = group,
           y = value,
           fill = stack)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",
             position = "stack", width = 0.6) + 
    theme_classic() +
    theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = NA, fill=NA, size=0),
                            text = element_text(size = 8, family = "sans")) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
    labs(x = "", y = expression(paste("Relative Abundance(%)"))) + 
    facet_wrap(~facet, strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x") +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
          panel.spacing = unit(0, "line"), 
          strip.background = element_blank(),
          strip.placement = "outside") +
    theme(plot.title.position = 'plot',
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

Comment: scale_fill_manual does not look to change anything but the color patterns to me. Adding `+ scale_fill_manual(values = c('red', 'yellow', 'black', 'orange'))` renders the same plot, with different colors

Comment: As the issue is about adding `scale_fill_manual` and `geom_col_pattern` it would be easier to help you if you show the code including these functions and an image of the result which may clarify what you mean by *those will not work as they turn my plot back into one group.*.